# Add Textblock to PivotItem with code, how?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a list of items(names of image) in a isolated storage. If i'm not wrong, all items in the pivot item is a textblock. How do I add or bind it there so when I select it, it will load the image.

```
private void LoadFromLocalStorage()
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        string[] fileNames = store.GetFileNames();

        foreach (string s in fileNames)
        {
            //Add a textblock item in pivot? 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `PivotItem` add a named panel that you add these elements  to:

```
<PivotItem>
  <StackPanel x:Name="container"/>
</PivotItem>
```

Then add the TextBlocks in code-behind as follows:

```
    foreach (string s in fileNames)
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock() { Text = s };
        container.Children.Add(txt);
    }
```

You can use any panel you wish, or set properties on the element you add to define layout.

Comment: How do i give it a eventhandler where i click it will load the picture(Maybe another form with the picture)

Comment: @RainbowHat that is a new question. If my answer has helped, please upvote / mark as answer. You can't just keep asking more questions on the same 'thread'

Comment: Would be nice if you can help me out on that too

Comment: @RainbowHat add an event handler, txt.MouseLeftButtonUp += ... Visual Studio will auto-complete and generate a method for your which will be executed on click.

Comment: Hmm its like a list of text, any way to design the textblock?